# How to access themeDisplay Object in liferay 6.2 GA1

Tags: liferay-6

I need to get ThemeDisplay object so that I can access page URL in my controller.
I am trying with the following code but it gives null-pointer exception

```
@RenderMapping
public String showItems(ModelMap model, RenderResponse response, RenderRequest request)       
{
   ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
   Layout layout = themeDisplay.getLayout();
   String uri = layout.getFriendlyURL();
   return "home";
}
```

I have tried printing request attribute for WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY but it is null in my request .

I have added following dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
  <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add maven dependency jar of version 6.2 instead of 6.1.2. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: Is your issue got resolved?

Comment: Thanks for reply.but it didn't work for me either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution for my question :)
I have added scope for portlet-service jar as provided and it worked for me.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
   <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
   <version>6.2.0-B1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hope this help some one in future.